# incompatible types: Person(class) cannot be converted to java.util.arraylist<person>

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got 2 classes, Person and network.
I have an arraylist of objects representing persons and a method that returns a list of their friends. I'm trying to use this method to add the friends to each person.

```
public void loadNetwork() {    
    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Person person : persons) {
        System.out.println("Finding friends of " + person.getName());
        ArrayList<String> friendNames = friends(person.getName());

        for (String friendName : friendNames) {
            System.out.println(" * " + friendName);
            ArrayList<Person> friendS = lookupPerson(friendName);
            for(Person friend : friendS) {
                person.addFriend(friend);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whatever i do i cant seem to make it work, and i keep getting the error.
Method that returns their friends.

```
public ArrayList<String> friends(String personName) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (personName.equals("Aage")) {
        result.add("Bård");
        result.add("Dag");
    } else if (personName.equals("Bård")) {
        result.add("Aage");
        result.add("Christian");
    } else if (personName.equals("Christian")) {
        result.add("Bård");
        result.add("Dag");
        result.add("Even");
    } else if (personName.equals("Dag")) {
        result.add("Aage");
        result.add("Christian");
        result.add("Liv");
    } else if (personName.equals("Even")) {
        result.add("Christian");
        result.add("Fridtjof");
        result.add("Gerda");
        result.add("Hulda");
        result.add("Ingrid");
        result.add("Jorunn");
    } else if (personName.equals("Fridtjof")) {
        result.add("Even");
        result.add("Gerda");
        result.add("Hulda");
    } else if (personName.equals("Gerda")) {
        result.add("Even");
        result.add("Jorunn");
        result.add("Ingrid");
    } else if (personName.equals("Hulda")) {
        result.add("Even");
        result.add("Fridtjof");
    } else if (personName.equals("Gerda")) {
        result.add("Even");
        result.add("Jorunn");
        result.add("Ingrid");
    } else if (personName.equals("Ingrid")) {
        result.add("Even");
        result.add("Gerda");
        result.add("Jorunn");
        result.add("Kerstin");
        result.add("Liv");
    } else if (personName.equals("Jorunn")) {
        result.add("Even");
        result.add("Gerda");
        result.add("Ingrid");
    } else if (personName.equals("Kerstin")) {
        result.add("Ingrid");
        result.add("Liv");
    } else if (personName.equals("Liv")) {
        result.add("Dag");
        result.add("Ingrid");
        result.add("Kerstin");
    }
    return result;
}
```

My lookupPerson method

```
public Person lookupPerson(String personName) {
    boolean personContain = persons.contains(new Person(personName));

    for (Person p: persons) {
        if (p.getName().equals(personName)) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: When you do `for (Person person : persons) {`, you loop over a List which was just initialised two lines above: the list will always be empty. Where do you get the error?

Comment: This is not code related but just to let you know, the plural of person is people, not persons. By the way, you have to add the stacktrace of your error and all the code required, for example, what does the `lookupPerson` method do?

Comment: What does `lookupPerson` do?

Comment: The message talks about ArrayList<Person>, thus it is not about friends, but most probably about lookupPerson

Comment: i've added my lookupPerson method

Comment: The error is at lookupPerson(friendName);

Answer (score 2):

According to this compilation error  :

> incompatible types: Person(class) cannot be converted to
>   java.util.arraylist

The problem is probably here as in the shown code, this is the single statement that could cause this kind of error :

```
    ArrayList<Person> friendS = lookupPerson(friendName);
```

`lookupPerson()` returns a `Person` and not an `ArrayList` of `Person` but you want to assign it to a `ArrayList` of `Person`.

And as a side note, you should program by interface by favoring `List` to `ArrayList` as declared type.

So to solve your problem, either change `lookupPerson()` to be declared as : 
`List<Person> lookupPerson()` or assign its result to a `Person` variable.

Comment: I've added my lookupPerson() method.

Answer (score 0):

You created and array that does NOT have any data in it. Your declaration is a new empty array.

ArrayList persons = new ArrayList<>();